# Java scripting and JMeter

Tags: json, jmeter

I have a job log request in a JSON file, that I need to post JSON file through Jmeter. Each request I post should have unique timestamp.

Do we have any options in JMeter to handle this Dynamically?

Below is my JSON request:

```
{
  "XXXX098": {
    "NumCopies": "1",
    "NumPages": "20",
    "Status": "done printing",
    "Title": "Spooling.jpg",
    "Username": "keshavka",
    "date": "23:06 Feb 5, 15",
    "print status": "cancel",
    "time": "1429036296",
    "timestamp done printing": "1434713950:130068" //--> Should be changed dynamically for every request (EPOC Timer)
  }
}
```

Comment: what sampler are you using?

Comment: any feedback on my answer ? if it was helpful it should be accepted and possibly upvoted so that it's helpful to others

Answer (score 0):

What about using jmeter __javaScript function or beanshell preprocessor?

Comment: tried it , but we cant pass the variable from bean shell preprocessor to a JSON file

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to vary is the date, you can use a JMeter function for the dynamic value:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time

Otherwise use a [CSV DataSet Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) element

Use [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) with Post Body selected to put the body

Comment: sry , NO , actually i cant put it in  body of a post request . it must be uploaded as a  JSON file in a request

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use __time function of jmeter?
You should try

Answer (score 0):

Inline [__time()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) function into your JSON payload as:

```
{
  "XXXX098": {
    "NumCopies": "1",
    "NumPages": "20",
    "Status": "done printing",
    "Title": "Spooling.jpg",
    "Username": "keshavka",
    "date": "23:06 Feb 5, 15",
    "print status": "cancel",
    "time": "1429036296",
    "timestamp done printing": "${__time(,)}" 
  }
}
```

By default __time() function returns current time in milliseconds since 1st Jan 1970, however you can control format using [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) patterns, see [How to Use JMeter Functions - Part III](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) for explanation and examples.

Comment: This works whenwe give This as a part og body in request , but when i upload a JSON file in a request this doesn't work